# How to fix ajax form redirecting to mailer page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, phpmailer

I am developing the contactus form in html page, the validation working perfectly, this code worked without validation, after validation its not working, but the page redirected to mailer.php, The AJAX not working, I tried all the way but didn't work. how can I fix this? any suggestion highly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<form  id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php"  class="wpcf7-form AdvancedForm" autocomplete="on">
<div class="form-group">
<input  id="cname" type="text" name="cname" value="" placeholder="NAME">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input id="cemail" type="email" data-missing="This field is required" data-mismatch="Please include a valid email"  name="cemail" value="" placeholder="EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input id="cnumber" type="text" maxlength="15" name="cnumber" value="" placeholder="MOBILE">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input id="csubject" type="text" name="csubject" value="" placeholder="SUBJECT">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea id="cmessage" draggable="false" name="cmessage" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="theme-btn btn-style-four">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="form-messages"></div>
</form>
```

This is Jquery for the validation and Ajax conditions.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#cname").validate({
expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
message: "Please enter the Name"
});
$("#cnumber").validate({
expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9\.\-\/]+$/)) return true; else return false;",
message: "Please enter a valid Phone number"
}); 
$("#csubject").validate({
expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
message: "Please enter the Subject"
});
$("#cemail").validate({
expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
message: "Please enter a valid Email ID"
});
$("#cmessage").validate({
expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
message: "Please enter the Message"
});

// Get the form.
var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

$('.AdvancedForm').validated(function(e){
// alert("Use this call to make AJAX submissions.");

// Stop the browser from submitting the form.
e.preventDefault();

// Serialize the form data.
$(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("please wait...");


var formData = $(form).serialize();

console.log($(form).attr('action'));
console.log(formData);

// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: $(form).attr('action'),
data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
$(formMessages).removeClass('error');
$(formMessages).addClass('success');

// Set the message text.
$(formMessages).text(response);

// Clear the form.
$('#cname').val('');
$('#cemail').val('');
$('#cnumber').val('');
$('#csubject').val('');
$('#cmessage').val('');

})
.fail(function(data) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
$(formMessages).removeClass('success');
$(formMessages).addClass('error');

// Set the message text.
if (data.responseText !== '') {
$(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
} else {
$(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you encapsulate your validation rules inside a function such that if everything is ok then the function should return true, then using if statement to test, like

```
if($validation){
then handle the ajax form submit
}
```